# Translating this sentence into mathematical symbols

Tags: probability

Well, first of all, english is not my mother language so please bear with me.
There's this probability question that makes me overthink:

> A mattress store sells only king, queen and twin-size mattresses. Sales records
>   at the store indicate that one-fourth as many queen-size mattresses are sold
>   as king and twin-size mattresses combined. Records also indicate that three
>   times as many king-size mattresses are sold as twin-size mattresses.
>   Calculate the probability that the next mattress sold is either king or queen-
>   size.

For one, I know how to solve this given that the equation is formed (which I have seen countless of times)

But my dilemma comes from translating this into mathematical ones. For example, if I let $T$ to be the frequency of twin mattress being sold, $K$ and $Q$ for king size and queen size respectively, the way I interpret

> one-fourth as many queen-size mattresses are sold
>   as king and twin-size mattresses combined

is $$\dfrac{1}{4}Q = K+T$$

Likewise for

> three
>   times as many king-size mattresses are sold as twin-size mattresses.

is $$3K = T$$

But somehow, my interpretation of these are somehow reversed (in the true solution). So if you guys could provide an insight of these, it will really help me (and my grammar).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is really a question about English language usage
rather than mathematics, but consider the following sentences:

> I bought ten bananas today, but the number of apples I bought was twice the number of bananas.
>
> I bought ten bananas today and twice as many apples.
>
> I bought twenty apples today and half as many bananas.
>
> I bought twenty apples today, and the number of bananas I bought was half the number of applies.
>
> I bought half as many bananas as apples today, that is, ten bananas and twenty apples.

All these sentences say the same thing.

If I was the only customer at the grocery store that day, then
on that day half as many bananas as apples were sold.
That is, the number of bananas was half of the number of apples,
$B = \frac 12 A.$

One could imagine a language in which the "half as many" comparison
worked the opposite way, that is, it meant $\frac12 B = A,$
but English is not such a language.

Comment: Indeed english is not that simple.
Thank you very much for this, I finally found a closure to this problem :)

Answer (score 1):

> Three times as many king-size mattresses are sold as twin-size mattresses.

Think of the statement like it answers a question.

Question: Compared to the number of twin-size mattresses sold, ***how many*** king-size mattresses are sold?

Answer: Compared to the number of twin-size mattresses sold, ***three times*** *as many* king-size mattresses are sold. (here, "as many" refers to the number of twin-size mattresses)

The English is misleading. The proximity of words wants us to think the opposite. You want to think "three times as many" directly affects "king-size mattresses", but in reality it's more like "three times as many (of twin-size mattresses) king-size mattresses".

The statement is equivalent to: 1) The number of king-size mattresses is three times the number of twin-size mattresses, and 2) For every twin-size mattress sold, three king-size mattresses are sold. They all mean $K=3T$.

> One-fourth as many queen-size mattresses are sold as king and twin-size mattresses combined.

Compared to the number of king and twin-size mattresses combined, only *one-fourth* as many queen-size mattresses are sold. Therefore, $Q=\frac{1}{4}(K+T)$.

---

Some other examples...

> "Her dog is as big as a small horse"

--> size of dog = size of small horse

> "Mike earns half as much money as Dan"

--> Mike's income = 1/2 * Dan's income

> "There are five times as many boys in the room, as there are girls"

--> number of boys = 5 * number of girls